# Implementation of Stack in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, abstract-data-type

So I have to implement an ADT, in this case a Stack in SWI-Prolog. I need help, because I'm new in this programming language, and don know how to start.

This started as an implementation in python(3) where I defined a class and added functions to work with (push, is_empty?,pop, peak). But now, I need to do something similar in prolog.

I have visited some other stackoverflow questions similar to mine, but I'm still helpless.

I think that is not only to define a list in SWI-Prolog,  Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention ADTs, I will use Logtalk (which you can run with most Prolog systems) to first define a stack protocol/interface:

```
:- protocol(stack_protocol).

    :- public(new/1).
    :- mode(new(--stack), one).
    :- info(new/1, [
        comment is 'Creates a new empty stack.',
        argnames is ['Stack']
    ]).

    :- public(empty/1).
    :- mode(empty(@stack), one).
    :- info(empty/1, [
        comment is 'True if the stack is empty.',
        argnames is ['Stack']
    ]).

    :- public(top/2).
    :- mode(top(?stack, ?element), zero_or_one).
    :- info(top/2, [
        comment is 'True if Top is the top element of the stack.',
        argnames is ['Stack', 'Top']
    ]).

    :- public(push/3).
    :- mode(push(?stack, ?element, ?stack), zero_or_one).
    :- info(push/3, [
        comment is 'Adds an element to the stack.',
        argnames is ['Stack0', 'Element', 'Stack']
    ]).

    :- public(pop/3).
    :- mode(pop(?stack, ?element, ?stack), zero_or_one).
    :- info(pop/3, [
        comment is 'Removes an element from the stack.',
        argnames is ['Stack0', 'Element', 'Stack']
    ]).

:- end_protocol.
```

We can now define an implementation for the stack ADT. The obvious choice is simply to use a list:

```
:- object(stack,
    implements(stack_protocol)).

    new([]).

    empty(Stack) :-
        Stack == [].

    top([Top| _], Top).

    push(Stack, Element, [Element| Stack]).

    pop([Element| Stack], Element, Stack).

:- end_object.
```

Assuming both protocol and object defined in a `stack.lgt` source file, a sample call would be:

```
| ?- {stack}.
...
% (0 warnings)

(4 ms) yes
| ?- stack::(
         new(S0),
         push(S0, 1, S1),
         push(S1, 2, S2),
         push(S2, 3, S3),
         top(S3, T),
         pop(S3, E, S)
     ).

E = 3
S = [2,1]
S0 = []
S1 = [1]
S2 = [2,1]
S3 = [3,2,1]
T = 3

yes
```

Is it worthy defining the protocol? Protocols are specially useful when several different implementations are expected (e.g. a dictionary or a random number generator). But, in this case, a list is such a natural candidate to implement a stack that the usefulness of defining a protocol is mainly for its educational value. In most cases, when a stack is required, programmers simply use a list directly.